# Javascript Object defined in Pages of Notes designer is unidentified on a subform

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-designer, hcl-domino

We have a javascript code running for a calendar functionality. This piece of code is present in a Notes subform in the Designer.(HCL Notes 11.0.1 FP8). The piece of code is as follows:

```html
<script type = "text/javascript">
Calendar.setup({
/* Code goes here */
)};</Script>
```

Whereas the object constructor of the Calendar and it's CSS are present in Pages in the Designer.

We are getting the following error upon using that functionality in the web application:

> "Calendar is undefined"

It looks like the Calendar object is not able to access the Object constructor present in the Pages section in the Designer.

However, if I paste the Object constructor code in the JS Header section instead of Pages, it is working as expected.

Any ideas on how to make this work?